# Java: Question: can this program leak with a creation of java array everytime within a while passing through a method can leak memory?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

I did this example, passing -Xmx64m

I know this program doesnt leak memory (or not?).
But I dont know how the garbage collector does it, because everytime I create a new double array.

Is it possible this program to have a memory leak? Because every while I create a new array of doubles?

Where the Garbege collector does collect the new double ?

```
public class TestLeakMemory {

private static float total;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long currtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeElapsed = 0;
    long lastTime = 0;
    long count = 0;
    while (timeElapsed < 6000000) {
        //Thread.sleep(100);
        count++;

        double arr1[] = new double[200000];
        double arr2[] = new double[200000];
        double arr3[] = new double[200000];
        float doSomething = doSomething(arr1, arr2, arr3);

        total += doSomething;

        timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - currtime;

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 3000) {
            System.out.println("totalMemory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() + ", freeMemory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() + ", count: " + count);
            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(total);
}

private static float doSomething(double[] arr1, double[] arr2, double[] arr3) {
    float total = 0;
    for (double d : arr1) {
        total += d;
    }
    for (double d : arr2) {
        total += d;
    }
    for (double d : arr3) {
        total += d;
    }

    return total;
}
```

}

Comment: this program does not have a memory leak.

Comment: When memory is needed, the garbage collector detects which arrays aren't _reachable_ (strongly referenced somewhere) anymore and removes them.

Comment: After each iteration of the `while` loop, the arrays created during that iteration become garbage.  The garbage collector will get to them eventually.

Comment: What exactly is your Question here? Did you get an error? Did you *not* get an error but expected one? Are you wondering how the garbage collector manages to keep up with all the garbage being generated here? What was your motivation in writing this Question? I’m voting to close as unclear. I suggest you edit for clarity.

Comment: I didn't say it had a memory leak. I was questioning... I was not sure it had or not because the program every time creates a new instance withing a loop. I think this community of StackOverflow is becoming a little intolerant... Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no memory leak here.

Just creating an object or array and then dropping its reference "on the floor" does not create a memory leak.  The garbage collector will discover that the object / array is no longer reachable and delete it.  This won't happen immediately, but it will happen before your application runs out of memory.

In Java, a memory leak occurs when objects are still reachable and they shouldn't be.  The GC doesn't know the objects won't be used again, and just keeps them.

For example, if you keep a list of all of those arrays in a `ArrayList` that is referenced by a `static` variable.  The collector has no way of knowing if those objects are (really) needed by your program.  So since they are reachable, it keeps them.  If you keep doing this, you run out of memory.

---

If you are getting OOMEs with that program, it is not due to a memory leak.  It would be due to the heap being too small.  But I don't think that is likely:   200,000 x 3 x 8 bytes is less than 5 megabytes, and you have capped the heap at 64 megabytes.

You *could* reuse those arrays to reduce object creation / deletion churn, but it is unclear if this would be worthwhile.  You example code is not representative of a real application.